# 3-layer Nested Quotes (bash)

Tags: bash, shell, sh, quotes, quoting

*Exuse: I know there are many questions about nested quotes but the answers to those I found are so specific to the questions that I wasn't able to apply them.*

I need to use multiple nested bash commands. The first two layers are

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "bash -c \"COMMAND1; COMMAND2; exec bash \""
```

To open a terminal and run multiple bash commands in it. 
For COMMAND1, I want to assign a value to a variable by the means of `read VAR`. In COMMAND2, I want to substitute an expression in a file with the variable's value. Since `sed -i 's#EXPRESSION#$VAR#' ~/Desktop/edit` needs a third layer of quotes, the only option left is unsing single quotest but that would of course ignore the variable.
I have tried many things but the outcome was always that either the expression was substituted with '' or with '$VAR' or with 'VAR'.

I ask for help because I really don't know what to change here. I am greatly grateful for any help!

TL;DR:
How do I correctly substitute EXPRESSION with user input here if this is wrong:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "bash -c \"read VAR; sed -i 's#EXPRESSION#$VAR#' ~/Desktop/edit; exec bash \""
```

Comment: May be you can split the argument to "bash -c" in several parts, and then join them once finally? Something like part1=".."; part2=".." bash -c $part1$part2 or something like that?

Comment: What happens if you do `x-terminal-emulator -e "bash -c \"read VAR; sed -i \\\"s#EXPRESSION#\\\$VAR#\\\" ~/Desktop/edit; exec bash \""`?

Comment: @linuxfan, At runtime, $part1$part2 are replaced by the String they represent. So wouldn't that be the same in the end?

Comment: melpomene, yours works! This is great, thank you so much!

Comment: @user6287736 no, it is not the same: substitution has certain rules, and breaking complex things in smaller ones can help. Anyway melpomene's comment seems to solve, so good is good.